# PHP Concatenate Variable in URL string

Tags: javascript, php

```
<td><input type="submit" onClick="window.location.href='https://www.'.$myVariable.'.test.com'" value="Click!"></td>
```

I have a button that should go to 1 of 8 possible url's - I have the logic to get the variable however I seem to run into an issue here. I get an error saying

```
Unresolved Variable: $myVariable
```

Is this because I am within a HTML table?

I even tried using `.<?=$myVariable?>.` between the strings and still didnt work. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Try to inspect the element after the page has loaded, and see that button link after rendering...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just output php variable inside one string:

```
<td><input type="submit" onClick="window.location.href='https://www.<?php=$myVariable; ?>.test.com'" value="Click!"></td>
```

Comment: it worked! Thank you- that solution completely flew over my head didnt even think about it haha

Answer (score 3):

Use `<?=$myVariable?>` or `<?php=$myVariable?>` if you don't have short tags enabled.

```
<td><input type="submit" onClick="window.location.href='https://www.<?=$myVariable?>.test.com' value="Click!"></td>
```

Another option is using [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) (my favorite) to include the `html` and `php` code, this way you don't have to concern about `quotes` or `concatenation` i.e.:

```
<?php
echo <<< LOL
<td><input type="submit" onClick="window.location.href='https://www.{$myVariable}.test.com'" value="Click!"></td>
LOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<td><input type="submit" onClick="window.location.href=<?php echo "'https://www.".$myVariable.".test.com'"; ?>" value="Click!"></td>
```

Just do php echo to your variable string.

Answer (score 0):

You're just getting complicated because of concatenations, so I'll just split them.

```
<?php
    $fullUrl = "https://www.{$myVariable}.test.com"; // Repeat for every variable
    $locationHref = "window.location.href='{$fullUrl};'";
?>

<td>
    <input type="submit" onClick="<?=$locationHref; ?>" value="Click!" />
</td>
```

As a sidenote, if you want to stop the normal submit of the form and actually do some processing with AJAX, you need to catch `onsubmit` on your `<form>` element (and `return false` on that attribute, or the form will submit anyway).

Right now you're redirecting using Javascript blocking your form submit (in strict terms, you're redirecting and also submitting, but not waiting for it to finish, which could lead to issues).